# Viewpager is pushed up when i push Toolbar

Tags: java, android, xml, android-viewpager, toolbar

i have problem with `toolbar` When I push him up , `viewpager` go up to the top also , And leave space at the bottom (see picture ) Any solution to solve this problem.

this is my activity_main :

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:background="#fafafb">
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
            android:elevation="5dp"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="2dp"
            android:elevation="10dp"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/tabs"
        android:background="#fafafb"
        android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: What is the layout inside view pager ? can you post here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove :

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

From your `ViewPager`

The support library contains a special string resource `@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior` that maps to `AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehavior`, which is used to notify the `AppBarLayout` when scroll events occur on this particular view.

Read this for more [Clarification](http://guides.codepath.com/android/handling-scrolls-with-coordinatorlayout)

Comment: thanks @rafsanahmad007 , but When delete it nothing has changed now without push toolbar The space at the bottom remains show

Comment: you need to remove the bottom margin: `android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"`  from viewpager.

Comment: already deleted it but the last item in listview doesn't show

Comment: thank you i put 0dp to android:layout_marginBottom="0dp" and works fine

Comment: Hello! Welcome to stack overflow! you should mark the answer as correct for future references....